# Display all data in a row using mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, nosql

I have a collection myCollection,

```
ID    DateTime              myID   Cost   Flag

1  '2016-07-01T00:00:00'    2048      1    'O'
2  '2016-07-02T00:00:00'    2049      2    'O'
```

if I write sql query for it

```
"select DateTime, myID,Flag, min(Cost) from myCollection group by DateTime, myID"
```

it will display all the fields in data e.g

```
  DateTime, myID,Flag, min(Cost)
```

but in mongo aggregation framework I can group like

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                DateTime: '$DateTime',
                myID: '$myID'
            },
            minCost: { $min: '$Cost' }
        }
    }
])
```

which will return me

```
DateTime, myID, min(Cost)
```

but I need `"Flag"` field also in single query. I tried out `$Push` but it works only for an array.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, the query

```
select DateTime, myID,Flag, min(Cost) from myCollection group by DateTime, myID
```

is invalid in the select list because the column `Flag` is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

In MongoDB, to be able to include the field `Flag` in the aggregate query, you must apply an accumulator operator on the field and in this case you may either use the **[`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first)** or **[`$last`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/#grp._S_last)** accumulator operators to return the field value within the aggregation.

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "DateTime": '$DateTime',
                "myID": '$myID'
            },
            "minCost": { "$min": '$Cost' },
            "Flag": { "$first": '$Flag' }
        }
    }
])
```

in the above, the **[`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first)** accumulator operator applied on the Flag field will return a `Flag` value from the first document for each group. Order is only defined if the documents are in a defined order.